# Can't access my play store account

Tags: google-play-store

Due to some reason my phone got stuck. I took out the battery and put it back and restarted my phone, but after that the time shown in my phone was in a back date. As a result I'm getting "I can't access play store". I even removed my account and now I try to login, but still can't access.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have a network connection? What Android version are you on?

Comment: `my phone was in a back date` did you update the time & date?

Comment: @Izzy I am using cyanogenmod 11,I have network connection everything but it seems that after removing the account and again I tried to add my google account it did not work ,so I finally flashed it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why did I read "black in time", which makes no sense: But as you wrote "my phone was in a back date" – ***Check your time settings, please!***

If your device time is too far off, certificates will cause trouble, which finally results in exactly that: no secure connection possible, and you cannot access your account. In cases like that it often helps to set the time *manually* (must not be to the second, if it's a minute off it's still fine). Then try again. You can set time adjustment to "automatic" again later.

Background: Certificates have a "livetime", including a start and an end. If your device is outside this frame, the certificate is either only valid "in the past" or "in the future", but not "now". So your device will *reject* it. Without a valid certificate, the *Google Play* app won't be able to establish a secured connection, and thus give you an "unable to access" (or similar) error.

Same applies btw. to other apps using secured connections – including the web browser when accessing sites via `https`. The latter you can use to check whether you've tapped into this trap: Start your web browser, try accessing e.g. `https://www.google.com/`, and see what happens. If you get a "certificate warning", that's it.

Comment: @user202476 If one of the answers here provided the solution, don't forget to mark it such (by clicking the check-mark next to it) :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to delete the data of the Play Store under Settings->Apps->All->Play Store?

Answer (score -1):

Also try logging into the play store on your PC's browser.